# Counting the number of occurrences of specific item for unique number

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I tried using formulas but these didn't work as expected. My boss has given me a file which contains data on 7,000 employees and lists monthly pay items such as salary, allowance etc. I need to summarize in one sheet like the below, for eg 1234 was paid salary every month so the Salary should reflect 12, whereas he received education allowances only for two months so the count will show as `2` under Education.

I take the data from a different sheet, which will have employee ID on cell A:A, and pay items on C:C (Salary for 12  months will be in 12 rows like that for each pay item).

The expectation is a new sheet with count under each column of pay description how many items are there for each employee:

```
Employee ID Salary  Home Allowance  Education   Sodexo
1234          12                      2 
45678               
91011
```

Comment: What I need is your salary if I am to do your work for you? XD

Comment: Sharing is caring bro...you can ask me any question related to Taxation/ ways to save tax ....i can give you the answer...i am a finance guy...

Comment: If this was sharingiscaringbro.com then sure. But this is SO XD Please see how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Admittedly, my comment was rude but irresitible so I apologize.

Comment: Look into COUNTIF function:

Comment: Thanks pnuts, i used to do it in pivot table earlier...Sorry i forgot to mention that earlier.....the same set of data comes every month..And i spent a whole day every time to clean up and make it to the required format with pivot table....So i was just wondering if anyone out there can help me on a macro....with which i can automate the whole process,....I have used record macro to do all the process...this is the only thing which i am not able to automate due to lack of technical knowledge..... :( ....sorry to all i am being too greedy on this...

Comment: Thanks Macro....there are two criteria, one is the ID and second one is the compensaiton variable...which is not allowing me to do the Countif function

Comment: please give sample of data sheet (with the challenges) so we can help you...

Comment: Sorry i am new to this so i dont know to share in this portal...so i am sharing it from google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XmgDms-wpiyoUmF0zd1D4EgDOgpFnpXLiK-VaEWEiBk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The challenge is, other than doing a pivot table...is there a way we can count the number of variables for each individual....the countif function wont work as there are two criteria....count the number of the header for the employee id.......as suggested by a user recorded the pivot table.....but if we can have a way some other formula which is not common....that would be great....i tried lot of check on count, countif, countifs, counta, match...but nothing seems to work....I have a lot of vlookups going through the spreadsheet...so it will have effect on pivot so cannot trust pivot....

Comment: Anyluck guys.....apologizes for not being clear...and appreciate all your help

Comment: I did it guys with the help of loops...thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

- select your data
- insert pivot table
- put the employee id as a row field, the pay item type in column field, and the amount as a data field (right click to summarize by count)

That might be just what you need.

Record yourself doing that, post the code, and we can help you tweak it so it works every month.